# During which state I should save and Load one single data in an android app

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am creating a simple application where I display quotes. However I want to set up a counter which gets passed to the API and the API fetches the quote. So I researched a bit and found out that I can use SharedPreferences for this.

However my question is Where should I save and Load my counter. I am very confused.

Should I load my counter during OnCreate method and Save it in OnPause method?
I know I can't save it during ondestroy method because i read that ondestroy method doesn't get called everytime.

Can Anyone help me out? This is my first time dealing with android cycles in detail.

Thank you.

Comment: any reason why you don't want to do both incrementCounter and Save at the same time (during OnCreate)? or save it immediately after your API fetches the quote?

Comment: Oh yeah, I can do that. Increment the counter and then save it.
Just wondering is it efficient to do that?

Comment: Increment and saving the counter is more efficient and cleaner than having a   counter field persist throughout the lifecycle of the app (just for the purpose of saving it   before app exits).

Comment: Alright. Thank you :D